# Get last date of current Hijri month with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hijri

is there any way to get first and last date of current Hijri month with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The following function will return information about the Hijri Date as 7 elements in an array given a Gregorian date. This can be the current date or any other date.

```
The information returned by the function is:

[0] The Gregorian Date (the input date) in YYYY-MM-DD format
[1] The Hijri Day (Number) (1-30)
[2] The Hijri Month (String)
[3] The Hijri Year (Number)
[4] Total Days in the Hijri Month (Number) (29 or 30)
[5] The Gregorian Date that the Hijri Month starts on (Date object)
[6] The Gregorian Date that the Hijri Month ends on   (Date object)
```

The test case examples provide the information on today's Hijri Date (and month) and another date.

```js
/*********************************************************************
* @function      : getHijriMonthInfo(date)
* @purpose       : Returns information on a Hijri Month for a given Gregorian Date
* @version       : 1.00
* @author        : Mohsen Alyafei
* @date          : 06 Feb 2022
* @Licence       : MIT
* @param         : {date} a valid Date Object
* @returns       : An Array of seven (7) elements with the following data:
*                  [0] The Gregorian Date (the input date) in YYYY-MM-DD format
*                  [1] The Hijri Day (Number) (1-30)
*                  [2] The Hijri Month (String)
*                  [3] The Hijri Year (Number)
*                  [4] Total Days in the Hijri Month (Number) (29 or 30)
*                  [5] The Gregorian Date that the Hijri Month starts on (Date object)
*                  [6] The Gregorian Date that the Hijri Month ends on   (Date object)
**********************************************************************/

function getHijriMonthInfo(date) {
let startDate= new Date(date),
    c= 'en-u-ca-islamic-umalqura-nu-latn',  // use 'islamic-umalqura' calendar for the islamic date
    d= startDate, gDays=0, iMonthTotalDays= 0, i_Day, n='numeric',
    iDay  =new Intl.DateTimeFormat(c,{day  :n}).format(startDate),
    iMonth=new Intl.DateTimeFormat(c,{month:'long'}).format(startDate),
    iYear =new Intl.DateTimeFormat(c,{year :n}).format(startDate).split(" ")[0];
for (let i=0; i<32; i++) {
    i_Day= new Intl.DateTimeFormat(c,{day:n}).format(d); // Hijri day
    if (+i_Day>iMonthTotalDays) iMonthTotalDays= i_Day, gDays++;
    else break;
    d= new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate()+1));               // next Gregorian day
    }
let gEndT = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+gDays-2)),
    gEnd  = new Date(gEndT),
    gStart= new Date(gEndT.setDate(gEndT.getDate()-iMonthTotalDays+1));
return [new Date(date).toISOString().split("T")[0],+iDay,iMonth,+iYear,iMonthTotalDays,gStart,gEnd];
}
//==================================================================
// Test Cases
//==================================================================
output(getHijriMonthInfo(new Date(Date.now()))); // today's date
output(getHijriMonthInfo("2022-04-22"));         // 22 April 2022
//==================
function output([gDate, iDay, iMonth, iYear, iMonthTotalDays, gStart, gEnd]) {

console.log(`
Gregorian Date            : ${gDate}
Hijri Day                 : ${iDay}
Hijri Month               : ${iMonth}
Hijri Year                : ${iYear}
Total Days in Hijri Month : ${iMonthTotalDays}
Hijri Month Starts on     : ${gStart}
Hijri Month Ends on       : ${gEnd}
`
);
}
//==================
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to getting the last day of the current Hijri month is to use the ECMAScript proposal "[Temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal)" which is currently in Stage 3 of Active Proposals.

```html
<script type='module'>

// ====== load Temp polyfill (not needed after implementation) ========
import * as TemporalModule from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@js-temporal/polyfill@0.3.0/dist/index.umd.js'
//=====================================================================

const Temporal = temporal.Temporal;

// Note using 'islamic-umalqura' Calendar

let daysIncurrentHijriMonth = Temporal.PlainDate.from( Temporal.Now.plainDateISO()).withCalendar('islamic-umalqura').daysInMonth;

console.log("Current Hijri Month is: ", daysIncurrentHijriMonth," days");

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

have you tryied using
`new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-TN-u-ca-islamic', {day: 'numeric', month: 'long',weekday: 'long',year : 'numeric'}).format(Date.now());`

This returns the current hijri date, you may need to do some calculations to get first and last

Comment: How would you do that `new Intl.DateTimeFormat()`? as the `Date()` object is Gregorian based and not possible to do any Hijri date calculations using the `Intl.DateTimeFormat()`.